# Check if rightBarButtonItem exists or not

Tags: iphone, xcode, rightbarbuttonitem

Is there a way to check if the current view already has a right bar button, something like:

```
if (FOO_CODE.rightBarButtonItem != nil) {
    // don't create one
} else {
    // create one
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem)
```

has the same effect, testing equality to nil is redundant

Comment: This is incorrect in the case of the rightBarButtonItem because it's an optional. The compiler will actually flag this as an error if you try it on Swift 4 and above, and will tell you to add `!= nil`

Answer (score 3):

```
if (self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem != nil)
{
   // I exists
} else {
   // I don't exists
}
```